# Python program using lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that displays an employee's id, their hours, payrate, and wages.

The second part of the program requires that the user enter an employee's Id so that their wage will be displayed.

The first part of my program works fine up until `pay=input()`.
When I try to run it with the second part, it says that there is a syntax error.

Here is my program:

```
employeeId=[56588,45201,78951,87775,84512,13028,75804]
hours=[40,41,42,43,44,45,46]
payrate=[13.60,13.50,13.40,13.30,13.20,13.10,13.00]
wages=[544.00,553.50,562.80,571.90,580.80,589.50,598.00]
print('employeeId\thours\t\tpayRate\t\twages')
print(employeeId[0],'\t\t',hours[0],'\t\t',payrate[0],'\t\t',wages[0])
print(employeeId[1],'\t\t', hours[1],'\t\t',payrate[1],'\t\t',wages[1])
print(employeeId[2],'\t\t',hours[2],'\t\t',payrate[2],'\t\t',wages[2])
print(employeeId[3],'\t\t',hours[3],'\t\t',payrate[3],'\t\t',wages[3])
print(employeeId[4],'\t\t',hours[4],'\t\t',payrate[4],'\t\t',wages[4])
print(employeeId[5],'\t\t',hours[5],'\t\t',payrate[5],'\t\t',wages[5])
print(employeeId[6],'\t\t',hours[6],'\t\t',payrate[6],'\t\t',wages[6])


pay=input("Would you like to a see a specific employee's gross pay? Y/N:")
if pay=='Y'or pay=='y':
    ID=input('enter employee Id:')
    if ID=='56588':
        print(ID': $',wages[0])
    elif ID=='45201':
        print(ID': $',wages[1])
    elif ID=='78951':
        print(ID': $',wages[2])
    elif ID=='87775':
        print(ID': $',wages[3])
    elif ID=='84512':
        print(ID': $',wages[4])
    elif ID=='13028':
        print(ID': $',wages[5])
    elif ID=='75804':
        print(ID': $',wages[6])
else:
    print(' ')
```

I'm seeing the following syntax error:

```
  File "code.py", line 19
    print(ID': $',wages[0])
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can you please show the complete error traceback?

Comment: There is no error traceback. a popup come up saying 'syntax error'

Comment: I've added the syntax error. Note that the syntax error does include a line number (line 19), which would make it easier for you (or anyone reading here) to find the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a comma in your `print()` calls, specifically between `ID` and the following string.

Comment: Yep, you can't just run the variable ID and a string together, you either need to concatenate them with `+` or add a comma to make them separate arguments.